# Hadoop kerberos ticket auto renew

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, kerberos

I'm facing some problems downloading big folders from HDFS using the command:

```
hadoop fs -get /path/to/hdfs/big/folder .
```

The folder is big (almost 3TB) and the kerberos ticket has a lifetime of 10 hours and a renawable lifetime of 7 days.

The download takes more than 10 hours and so I can't complete the operation (kerberos security exception). Is there any way to set the auto-renewal of the ticket for the get operation?

Comment: See https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/9394/kerberos-ticket-isnt-being-renewed-by-solr-when-st.html

Comment: Thanks @RemusRusanu but the proposed solution works for _solr_ , I have problems with the **get** operation.

Answer (score 1):

*"renewable lifetime of 7 days"* means that you can renew the ticket *explicitly*, without providing a password, for 7 days; each renewal gives you 10h more to go.

I know of a single auto-renewal (and auto-recreation) mechanism bundled with Linux, and it's part of SSSD. So if you want to delegate Linux auth to an OpenLDAP or Microsoft AD service, after several weeks of debugging *(...if you are lucky enough to ever succeed...)*, you will have -- optionally -- a Kerberos ticket managed for you by the OS.

There is also an auto-renewal thread started by the Hadoop Kerberos library, but it applies only to the tickets found in the cache before the connection; if you create the ticket yourself using the library (and a keytab) then it will not be renewable -- *one of the many things the Kerberos implementation of Java does not handle well* -- and will have to be re-created periodically.

---

Bottom line: you could try this kind of trick, to renew the ticket in the background until you release a "lock" after the transfer has completed.

```
touch lock.txt
kinit *************
{
  while [[ -f lock.txt ]]
  do
    kinit -R
    sleep 5m
  done
} &

hdfs dfs ***************
rm -f lock.txt
# backround process will terminate within 5m
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved my problem as follow:

**PART 1**

```
#set the kerberos ticket cache location
export KRB5CCNAME=/tmp/my_krbtkt

#create a renewable ticket (10 hours lifetime + renewable for 7 days)
kinit -r7d -l10h

#execute the long time command 
hadoop fs -get /path/to/hdfs/big/folder .
```

**PART 2**

Schedule inside the crontab a kerberos ticket renewal (i.e., every 6 hours):

```
0 */6 * * * kinit -R -c /tmp/my_krbtkt
```

Comment: You are right, with this solution you have to remove manually the renewal from the crontab when the work is finished.