# Kerberos auto update for "renew until"

Tags: java, hadoop, kerberos, auto-renewing, keytab

Given with keywords like **Kerberos "renew until" auto**, doesn't find threads that can solve my problem, so posting here.

I create a keytab which contains following ticket lifetime info

```
Valid starting: 09/14/2018 13:05:01 
Expires: 09/15/2018 13:05:01
renew until: 09/19/2018 09:26:37
```

Based on [Hadoop kerberos ticket auto renew](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43189044/hadoop-kerberos-ticket-auto-renew)

I am able to renew ticket extending **Expires** date without a problem.

Now another problem is **renew until** is set to expire after 7 days.

My question:

- Which command similar to `kinit -R` can auto extend **renew until** date so that I don't need to reissue `kinit -kt mine.keytab my-principal` for getting a new ticket for my keytab?
- Or any API that can achieve the same effect? With following Hadoop APIs, based on https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-14-x/topics/sg_kerberos_troubleshoot.html, I can execute the code but I don't find **renew until** gets updated.

  ```
  UserGroupInformation.loginUserFromKeytab(principal, keyPath)
  val currentUser = UserGroupInformation.getCurrentUser()   
  currentUser.checkTGTAndReloginFromKeytab
  val currentUser1 = UserGroupInformation.getLoginUser
  currentUser1.checkTGTAndReloginFromKeytab`
  ```

  `klist` shows that the date in the **renew until** section remains the same.

Edit: formatting

Comment: A keytab contains a (list of) password(s) encrypted with (multiple) algotithms. It does not contain tickets. A credential cache contains tickets.

Comment: The whole point of Kerberos is security. Tickets valid forever are a security liability. Hence tickets cannot live forever. End of questioning.

Comment: see whether k5start could help you. Once you setup a keytab for your kinit, you could do something like this, run it as a daemon. 

https://linux.die.net/man/1/k5start
k5start -K 60 -f /etc/sssd/serviceuser.keytab <username>

Comment: Any work around to this issue ?

Answer (score 2):

Renewable TGTs

When tickets are renewable, session keys are refreshed periodically without issuing a completely new ticket. If Kerberos policy permits renewable tickets, the KDC sets a RENEWABLE flag in every ticket it issues and sets two expiration times in the ticket. One expiration time limits the life of the current instance of the ticket; the second expiration time sets a limit on the cumulative lifetime of all instances of the ticket.

The expiration time for the current instance of the ticket is held in the End Time field. As with non-renewable tickets, the value in the End Time field equals the value in the Start Time field plus the value of the maximum ticket life specified by Kerberos policy. A client holding a renewable ticket must send it—presenting a fresh authenticator as well—to the KDC for renewal before the end time is reached. When the KDC receives a ticket for renewal, it checks the value of a second expiration time held in the Renew Till field. This value is set when the ticket is first issued. It equals the value in the tickets Start Time field plus the value of the maximum cumulative ticket life specified by Kerberos policy. When the KDC renews the ticket, it checks to determine if the renew-till time has not yet arrived. If it has not, the KDC issues a new instance of the ticket with a later end time and a new session key.

This means that administrators can set Kerberos policy so that tickets must be renewed at relatively short intervals—every day, for example. When tickets are renewed, a new session key is issued, minimizing the value of a compromised key. Administrators can also set cumulative ticket life for a relatively long period—one week or one month, for example. At the end of that time, the ticket expires and is no longer valid forrenewal.

So renew - until is part of the ticket, and it's max.value is limited on server side for security reasons. There is no workaround for that by design.